# How to match substring between two strings with RE2 regex?

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, re2

I need to extract the substring between "Design Brands > " and the first following pipe(|) character from of the following string:

```
"T-shirts|Brands > Port & Company|Design Brands > Montana Griz|Designs > TeamLB Griz > MTG31|T-shirts > TeamLB|T-shirts > Montana Griz"
```

This is within a google sheets function so I have to use Go's RE2 syntax

I would expect that the following expression would work

```
Design Brands > (.*)\|
```

However, the expression matches everything up to the last pipe in the string 
"`Montana Griz|Designs > TeamLB Griz > MTG31|T-shirts > TeamLB`" 
instead of everything up to the first occurance of a pipe in the string. I cant seem to figure out how to isolate just "Montana Griz" within a capture group.

Comment: How about making the `.*` [lazy](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution): [`Design Brands > (.*?)\|`](https://regex101.com/r/R15bm7/1/)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the lazy dot doesn't work in RE2. The working solution to this problem is not posted anywhere on stack overflow. I spent hours trying to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the dot lazy:

```
Design Brands > (.*?)\|
```

Or, if RE2 does not support lazy dot, then use this version:

```
Design Brands > ([^|]*)\|
```

### Demo

The second pattern says to:

```
Design Brands >    match "Design Brands > "
([^|]*)            then match and capture any character which is NOT pipe
\|                 finally match the first pipe
```

The `([^|]*)` is a trick for matching all content up to, but including, the first pipe which comes along.

Comment: Thank you! the second version works perfectly. though I am unfamiliar with what is happening within the square brackets in your expression, can you clarify?

Comment: @ColinWorf Check the updated answer.